# Importing JSON file to PHP [error Trying to get property of non-object]

Tags: php, json

I tried import one JSON file to PHP and use it, but the server return: "Trying to get property of non-object".
If I put manually the text in JSON file into a PHP file the server return correctly

index.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
        $dir = $_GET['dir'];
        $dir = $dir . "/";
    } else {
        $dir = "";
    }

    $about_dir = $dir . "about.json";


    //1st try
    $json_data = file_get_contents($about_dir);
    $json_a = json_decode($json_data, true);
    echo $json_a['T'];

    //2nd try
    $json = json_decode($json_data, true);
    print $json->{"T"};

    //3th try
    $json = '{"T": "Test","About": "About T"}';
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print $obj->{'About'};

    return $about_dir;
?>
```

about.json

```
[
    {
    "T": "Test",
    "About": "About T"
    }
]
```

What is wrong? I tried follow this example ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ). Also, I searched here in stackoverflow, but I never use JSON.
Someone can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: The square bracket notation of `about.json` indicates it's an array of objects, so you'd reference the first item with `$json[0]->About`

Answer (score 0):

You have to access object elements by using arrow and array elements by using square bracket. It's an array so you have to use square bracket here.

Answer (score 0):

I use a method similar to this to convert JSON to PHP

```
function json2object($json){ 
  $json_array = json_decode($json, true); 
  foreach($json_array as $k=>$v){ 
    $this->{$k}=$v;
  } 
}
```

So in your case you could use something like :

```
  $json_a = json_decode($json_data, true); 
  foreach($json_a as $k=>$v){ 
    $obj->{$k}=$v;
  }
```

Hope this works as well for you as it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json = '[
     {
    "T": "Test",
    "About": "About T"
    }
]';
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    //print $obj->{'About'};
    //print_r($obj);

    foreach($obj as $value)
    {
        echo $value->T;
        echo $value->About;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try, but seems that the error is in get_contents.

If I use this code:

```
$json = '{"T": "Test","About": "About T"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);    
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

The return is:

```
About T object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["T"]=> string(4) "Test" ["About"]=> string(7) "About T" }
```

If I import the contents:

```
$json = file_get_contents($about_dir);
//$json = '{"T": "Test","About": "About T"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

And write in about.json this line: {"T": "Test","About": "About T"}

The return is:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Yeh, the problem is that I file_get_contents import to a string.